# How to create a character like ► in Stackoverflow editor page?

Tags: html, css, unicode

[image]

I look up the soucecode of this pic.Just like this:

```
<p><span class="dingus">►</span> put returns between paragraphs</p>
```

Then I copy `►` character into my website.It looks like this:
[image]

As you can see,It turns out to be more wider? How to make a charater like Stackoverflow?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_geometric.asp

Comment: You have been a great help!

Comment: Just googled it ..:P

Comment: Do both your editor and your web site support UTF-8? What fond are you using to display the character?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I use webstrom to edit. So yes, editor support UTF-8. My website is just a static web page. I don't how to find whether it support UTF-8 or not.

Comment: @Lewis You can start by looking at the encoding displayed in the status bar of the IDE. You can then check other stuff like web server settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this .. to Print the required symbol you want ►

`<p style="font-size: 40px;">&#9658;</p>`

Comment: `&#9658;` is just the HTML entity for ►. There's no difference at all, unless the site does not support Unicode.

Answer (score 3):

If your site uses a text encoding that supports the complete Unicode catalogue (such as UTF-8) and your editor supports it as well, you can just copy and paste the symbol. It's nothing but text. In 2017 there's little reason to not use UTF-8.

The fact that you see the character suggests that it's working fine for you. However, you need to understand that it isn't a picture and the way it looks is entirely determined by font and other CSS styles, just like any other letter:

```css
div{
    font-size: 10pt;
}
.a{
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-transform:scale(2,1); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(2,1); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(2,1); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(2,1); /* Opera */
    transform:scale(2,1); /* W3C */
}
.b{
    color: orange;
    font-size: 15pt;
    text-shadow: 1px 2px 3px pink;
}
```

```html
<div>►</div>
<div class="a">►</div>
<div class="b">►</div>
```

Most system fonts will not even have a glyph for the character and the browser will default to some builtin char, but if you happen to be using custom fonts you may be able to pick a specific representation.

If it's a legacy site that doesn't use Unicode, HTML entities come to the rescue. Among other things, they're a mechanism to insert characters that cannot be represented in the character encoding used by the document. In this case, [the ► character](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%E2%96%BA) is U+25B6 aka [BLACK RIGHT-POINTING POINTER](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25b6/index.htm) so you can use its Unicode code point:

```
&#x25B6;
```

Comment: Just FYI, transform is more or less supported without the browser prefixes at this point

Comment: @SimonPertersen That's for the pointer. I confess I merely copied from the first text shadow generator that showed up in Google <:-)

Comment: i figured, it looks like one of those ;) just less redundant now days :D